# Подсчет изображений в посте

Tags: php, jquery

Нужно сделать подсчет фотографий в посте, может кто-то замечал, к примеру на майл ру, есть фото, а на нем есть маленькая иконка в правом верхнем углу с цифрой, которая отображает кол-во фотографий в посте. Как называется такой "эффект" и с помощью чего его можно сделать ?

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать метод

> count()
>
> http://php.net/manual/ru/function.count.php

при загрузке изображений(отправке $_POST) можно написать что-то типо такого:

```
$count_image = count($_POST['image']);
```

Comment: проще конечно же будет, если вы зальёте фрагмент кода, чтобы было яснее

Comment: Дело в том что у меня нет кода, так как я только наблюдал данный эффект на сторонних сайтах, и смотрю он стал достаточно распространен, вот и решил узнать как его сделать.

Comment: Тогда используйте метод count(), чтобы не усложнять себе жизнь)

Comment: Если ответ вам помог, пометьте ответ как правильный (рядом с ответом слева есть галочка). Это простое действие поможет в будующем кому-то со схожей проблемой сразу найти ответ =)

Comment: Дело  в том что я не совсем понял, логику работы данного метода. Я не понял, как картинки подсчитываются не заходя в сам пост (статью) ? Возможно я понял ! наверно делается запрос в базу данных, и парсятся теги из поста, после чего выводятся на главную картинку новостной "привьюшки"

Comment: Можете прислать хотя бы ссылку где вы такое видели?

Comment: Зайдите на майл ру, кликнине по любой новости, в правой стороне, внизу, будет написанно Фоторепортажи, и чуть ниже фотографии, на которых есть цифры (кол-во) фотографий в новости

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю саму логику, то при загрузке самого поста на странице соц.сетей, то вы загружаете определенное количество изображений к нему и при загрузке, когда приходит массив $_POST в обработчик идет подсчет методом count()

Comment: Либо же можно подсчитать элементы(в данном случае изображения) через jquery и цепочку селекторов, ведущих к данному посту
$('img').length

Comment: Как раз и нет ! кол-во картинок отображается без загрузки самого поста, к примеру, у вас раздел новости, вы в него заходите, и видете список привьюшек *с кол-вом* фотографий, и описание новости ! (не саму новость) так как в "пост" вы еще не вошли ! т.е кол-во картинко показывается ДО захода в сам пост, это означает что и подсчет идет ДО захода в пост, на сколько я понял, это только делается запрос в БД и парсятся из поста кол тегов и т д .

Comment: можно хоть через ajax передавать количество изображений в превью поста

Comment: не обязательно бд парсить
это лишнее действие

Comment: Ну тогда логика сводится к тому, при загрузке списка постов с "превьюшками и кол-вом на них фото" делается аяксом запрос по урл и подсчет фотографий найденных в нем, после чего подставляется слоем в превьюшку..

Comment: как вариант ))))